# Find any user's home directory

Tags: python-3.x

I've found several solutions for finding out a user's home directory of the user running said script, however, I'm writing a small script to make my life easier when creating vhost configurations for lighttpd or apache and would like to follow a scheme like so:

- /home/USER/html/example.com
- /home/USER/html/domain1.com

etc etc. However, I may decide at a later date whether I want to use `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/public_html` as a schema for certain domains.

The script, obviously has to run as root so it doesn't make sense to execute `os.getenv("HOME")`. I realize I can simply concatenate `homedir = "/home/%s/" % username` though.

I was just curious whether anyone ran across any solution to **retrieve a user's home directory of someone who's not executing the script.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `os.path.expanduser`: https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser